# UIWebView to open URLs in Safari, but not URLs that start with a #

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've tried using the code below to open links within my HTML5 app in Safari. However the code is also opening # links in Safari that are intended for internal navigation within the app. Are the links being prepended with HTTP which is causing them to be opened in Safari? If so, how could I modify this script to exclude them?

Thanks.

FOR REFERENCE

Please see the GIT repo here: https://github.com/philhudson91/flaming-cyril

Or could I write it to stop links from the domain I'm hosting on from opening?

UPDATE

Here's the code that I am now using...

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
NSURL *requestURL =[ [ request URL ] retain ];
NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"] invertedSet];
if ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ]) NSLog(@"HTTP"); if ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ]) NSLog(@"HTTPS"); if (( [ [requestURL absoluteString] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound )) NSLog(@"Not Local"); if (( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ])
    && ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {
    return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];
}
[ requestURL release ];
return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Is this a HTML5 app or a native app, I'm confused?  The 'script' you posted is native code but you reference your app as a HTML5 app.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm running my HTML5 app through a webview in the native app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following: (I haven't tested, this just verifies URL doesn't contain '#' when request scheme is http or https)

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
  NSURL *requestURL =[ [ request URL ] retain ];
  NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"] invertedSet];

  NSLog([requestURL absoluteString]);

  if ( ((( ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ]) || 
           ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ])) && 
         ( [ [requestURL absoluteString] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound ) ) || 
        ( [ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"mailto" ]) ) && 
      ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) ) {
      return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];
  }
  [ requestURL release ];
  return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify if the above isn't working because of a logic failure in the code or if its not working because it is correctly returning NO but its not behaving like you would expect?

Comment: It opens the external links within the application itself.. the internal (#) links are fine. Although this may indicate a logic failure.

Comment: Phil, The code looks fine to me and based on your comment, it is the logic that is going wrong. So, its simply a matter of isolating where it is going wrong. Here is what I would do to isolate: Add the following if conditions to see where the code is leading and combine them with && or || to generate the correct expression:

if ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"http" ]) NSLog(@"HTTP");
if ([ [ requestURL scheme ] isEqualToString: @"https" ]) NSLog(@"HTTPS");
if (( [ [requestURL absoluteString] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound )) NSLog(@"Not Local");

Comment: @Kiran many thanks for your help. The code identified that the function is seeing the internal (#) links as http requests. So it must be a logic problem?

Comment: Phil, does it ever show `"Not Local"` for `#` links? If it does, then its easy.. if not, then need to make sure the links are received properly

Comment: can you log `[requestURL absoluteString]` and see what it prints for local links

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance with Objective-C.. I've tried and failed to log it.. Do I have to convert the requestURL into a string before it can be logged?

Comment: Phil, I updated my answer. Can you try this and let me know what is happening ?

Comment: @Kiran Thanks again for your code, this is the debug log: `2012-09-14 20:38:15.725 BU News[13550:c07] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2012-09-14 20:38:15.730 BU News[13550:c07] Reachable WiFi
2012-09-14 20:38:15.790 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:43.404 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:58.658 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:58.658 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:58.790 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:59.509 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
2012-09-14 20:38:59.998 BU News[13550:c07] HTTP
`

Comment: Can you try to log with updated code? I want to see the actual URL you are getting when link is clicked..

Comment: Here's the log.. thanks again :) `2012-09-17 17:32:31.165 BU News[69242:c07] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2012-09-17 17:32:31.167 BU News[69242:c07] Reachable WiFi
2012-09-17 17:32:31.325 BU News[69242:c07] http://staging.bu-news.com:8000/
2012-09-17 17:32:53.847 BU News[69242:c07] http://staging.bu-news.com:8000/#
2012-09-17 17:33:02.244 BU News[69242:c07] http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/sep/16/animal-rights-shooting`

Comment: I tried changing * set to "http://staging.bu-news.com:8000/#" instead of just "#" and it opens the # link in the browser, however it just needs to effectively invert * set and it will work?

Comment: So, if the string is not the aforementioned URL, it would open in Safari?

Comment: This line of code: `NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]` will open the specified link in safari, it just need to not open the link and open everything else?

Comment: @kiran do you see what I mean about the above comment?

Comment: Sure Phil, thats why the condition compares against `.location == NSNotFound ` to make sure it does't exist.

Comment: But what I mean is, if I change it to  "staging.bu-news.com:8000/#" it opens every hash link in Safari... is there a way of inverting this? :)

Comment: Actually, I just noticed this: `return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];` Is there a reason why you are returning the negative of the app launch? Can you do `return [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease ] ];` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I have done that. Now whenever I clicked on a # link it opens it in Safari? Is there a way to invert this? I'm currently using `NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"http://staging.bu-news.com:8000/#"] invertedSet];` to determine # links.

Comment: Sorry do you have any other ideas please? It's almost there!

Comment: I have now put a bounty up for this :)

Comment: Phil, can you post your html page (or url) you are using? either here on github..

Comment: Yes, will do it in an hour or so if that's okay :)

Comment: Is there anything missing in the code or am I looking at the right place? I don't see any webview or calls to any domains..

Comment: Apologies, please see the repo here: https://github.com/philhudson91/flaming-cyril

Comment: Please open BU-News app in the root directory on GIT

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is quite fine but seems to have too many checks. I'd rather use something like that:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
    NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;

    if (([urlString rangeOfString:@"http://m.bu-news.com"].location != NSNotFound)) {
        return YES;
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
    return NO;
}
```

And it should be enough.

UPDATE: Did checkout your code and test it a bit. The code above works as expected: all navigation links opens inside app and all "Read full article" links opens in Safari. But didn't check all links, may be there are still some issues present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) this still isn't behaving exactly as expected. Basically the app needs to open all links that aren't from the same domain in Safari. Some links are still being opened within app. The Git repo is here if that helps :) https://github.com/philhudson91/flaming-cyril

Comment: This is working with some links but not all. I will recommit to the aforementioned repo :)

Comment: I agree, this approach is simpler than mine. Also updated my answer to make sure it works. The check for '#' was the wrong part.